# is there a way i can use Asterix(*) in tesseract?

Tags: cmd, ocr, tesseract

am trying to extract to use all my box file to extract characters and when i try this line

```
unicharset_extractor *.box
```

it gives me an error that it cannot find *.box instead of loading all box files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally made my own tool for that .
[link]http://code.google.com/p/serak-tesseract-trainer/
[image]

Answer (score 0):

That specific program does not support such syntax. You have to chain the names of all the box files and feed to it, such as:

```
unicharset_extractor lang.fontname.exp0.box lang.fontname.exp1.box ...
```

You can write a script (e.g., [train.ps1](http://vietocr.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/vietocr/jTessBoxEditor/trunk/tools/)) to automate the process.

http://code.google.com/p/tesseract-ocr/wiki/TrainingTesseract3

Comment: actually i made a tool to automate that... link http://code.google.com/p/serak-tesseract-trainer/